# why do we need the sdf element "collide with contact"?

Tags: collision

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Why do we need 'collide_without_contact' since this violates the physics laws? Any specific use cases?
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13275/why-do-we-need-the-sdf-element-%22collide-with-contact%22?/) by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 449 on 2016-05-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It's quite common to disable contact when running tests. This depends on what you're working on...

---

Originally posted by [debz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1306/debz/) with karma: 198 on 2016-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2016-05-12**:
It is also useful when creating an object that other objects should pass through, but still have collisions reported. This has been used to simulate mud.